# what is the method to use a different template to extend the statement {% block%}?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have this situation, my `base.html`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {% block album %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {% block artist %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then my `album.html`

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block album %}
    {% for album in albums %}
       <div>
            <h3><a href="{% url 'album_detail' pk=album.pk %}">{{album.name}}</a></h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Artist: {{album.artist}}</li>
                <li>Genre: {{album.genre}}</li>
                <li>Songs: , </li>
                <li>Vote: {{album.vote}}</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       <hr />
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

my `url.py`

```
...
url(r'^$', views.album, name='album'),
url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.album_detail, name='album_detail'),
...
```

my `views.py`

```
def album(request):
   albums = Album.objects.all()
   artists = Artist.objects.all()
return render(request,'polls/album.html',{'albums':albums,'artists':artists})

def album_detail(request, pk):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'polls/album_detail.html', {'album': album})
```

ok and album is render. But I would do the same thing with another file.html and extend the {% block artist %} but do not know how. please help me.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to ask. Looking at `album.html` and the way you have used `{% block album %} .... {% endblock %}`, it seems you already know how to use a `{% block %}` tag .

Comment: @AKS: I think luca_trep wants to render this two blocks at the same time on different html files.

Comment: I but I would like to extend the {% block%} artist with another file.html that will artist.html. the problem is that if I run the same procedure as for album.html, the web page will not let me see the artist.html content.

Comment: @trantu right! is a right thing to do or not?

Comment: Do you want to render album and artist in the same view side by side?

Comment: @luca_trep: you should use one view for album and artist

Comment: yes @AKS. I would do the same thing with another file.html who goes to work in the block {% block artist %}.

Comment: I tried to do, and data is added. but after if I enter this url <h3><a href="{% url 'artist_detail' pk=artist.pk %}">{{artist.name}}</a></h3> artist in the block, I django by mistake 'Reverse for' artist_detail 'with arguments' ()' and keyword arguments' {'pk': 'E-40'} 'not found. 1 pattern (s) tried: ['artist / (? P <pk> [0-9] +) / $'] ' and album_detail is in the url and  view

Comment: that's why I do not know if I have to extend the block to another artist file.html

Comment: @luca_trep: do you have def artist_detail(request,pk): in view.py?

Comment: yes @trantu you've defined.

Comment: @luca_trep: can you show it?

Comment: It means you don't have any url to show the details of an artist. What I can see from `urls.py`  that you only have urls to show `album_detail`.

Comment: @trantu @AKS this is my url `url(r'^artist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.artist_detail, name='artist_detail'),` and then in views `def artist_detail(request, pk):
    artist = get_object_or_404(Artist, pk=pk)
    artist_list = Artist.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'polls/artist_detail.html', {'artist': artist,'artist_list':artist_list})`

Comment: `r'^artist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'` should be `r'^artist/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$'`

Comment: @trantu changing the url with your own seems that now "E-40" has accepted but the next gives me the same thing only with '{' pk ':' Tu Pac '}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but it seems that you need to have the template HTML for "artist" and the HTML for "album" in separate `.html` files.

There is no way to do that the way you are going, because then you'd have two templates extending the `base.html` template, and you'd end up with two complete HTML documents.

So your two partial templates `artist-partial.html` and `album-partial.html` should *not* extend `base.html`.

```
{% for album in albums %}
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for artist in artists %}
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then, create another template file, maybe `album-container.html` that will be the container for the partial templates, extending from the base template.

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block artist %}
  {% include 'polls/artist-partial.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block album %}
  {% include 'polls/album-partial.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And that template is loaded in your view

```
return render(request,'polls/album-container.html',
              {'albums': albums,'artists': artists})
```

Comment: I did as you showed me @C14L, in fact it's better! but I always error `NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'artist_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'E-40'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['artist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

Comment: Work! Thank you! But now I give me the error I posted above if I add in "artist.html" the url `<a href="{% url 'artist_detail' pk=artist.pk %}">{{artist.name}}</a>`

Comment: If your `artist.pk` can look like "E-40" then you need to fix your `urls.py` definition for the `artist_detail` url, in particular, the regular expression that is now `'artist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'`. It should probably include characters and dashes, like `'artist/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$'`.

Comment: changing the url with your own seems that now "E-40" has accepted but the next gives me the same thing only with '{' pk ':' Tu Pac '}'

Comment: Because there are whitespaces in the pk. Probably not a good idea to have whitespaces in the primary key, because it will look ugly in the URL as `%20` and is not easily noticeable when looking at the pk. The url regex would be `'artist/(?P<pk>[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+)/$'`, adding the " ". But better to remove any white spaces from your primary keys. Why not use Django's default Interger values?

Comment: In fact, now it works thanks for the response and the advice @C14L! But how do I use Django's default Interger values?